# Python pandas plotting

Tags: python, pandas, plot

There is my code (example code from book about machine learning), but it doesn't appear pd.plotting.scatter_matrix in the end.

```
import sys
import mglearn as mglearn
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import scatter_matrix
import tkinter
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import IPython
import sklearn
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

iris_dataset = load_iris()
print("Ключи iris_datasets: \n{}".format(iris_dataset.keys()))
print(iris_dataset['DESCR'][:193] + "\n...")
print("Названия ответов: {}".format(iris_dataset['target_names']))
print("Первые пять строк массива data:\n{}".format(iris_dataset['data'][:5]))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
iris_dataset['data'], iris_dataset['target'], random_state=0)

# print("X: \n" + format(X_train))

iris_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(X_train, columns=iris_dataset.feature_names)
grr = pd.plotting.scatter_matrix(iris_dataframe, c=y_train, figsize=(15, 15), marker='o',
hist_kwds={'bins': 20}, s=60, alpha=.8, cmap=mglearn.cm3)
```

Try to do smtng like `grr.plot()`, there is no mistakes but graphic doesn't appear.. Who's know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to use `matplotlib.pyplot` for plots

add this to the imports

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Then at the very bottom of the file

```
plt.show()
```

You can force `pandas` to do it without importing `matplotlib` but all you are doing there is finding somewhere that `matplotlib` has been imported in `pandas`, and calling the same `show` function.